# Memory leak when using avplayer and opengl

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, opengl-es, avfoundation

**Edit 3**

I have found the root cause. `CADisplayLink` has a strong reference of the target. So it makes Retain Cycles.

**Edit 2**

Now I think is the memory issue causing the crash.

What I am doing is capture the output of the player and draw it on the opengl layer.

```
AVPlayerItem *item = ...;
if (!self.player) {
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
} else {
    [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
}

NSDictionary *pixBuffAttributes = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
self.videoOutput = [[AVPlayerItemVideoOutput alloc] initWithPixelBufferAttributes:pixBuffAttributes];
[self.player.currentItem addOutput:self.videoOutput];

[self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[self.player play];
```

In the callback of `DisplayLink`

```
CMTime itemTime = [self.videoOutput itemTimeForHostTime:CACurrentMediaTime()];
BOOL hasNewContent = [self.videoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTime];
if (hasNewContent) {
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [self.videoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:itemTime itemTimeForDisplay:NULL];
    // creat texture with pixelBuffer
    // display texture on opengl surface
    if (pixelBuffer != NULL) {
        CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
    }
}
```

There is no memory leak by instruments, but memory is rising.
[image: memory issue2]

**Edit 1:**

I have found a workaround. the resolution of "video_1" and "video_3" is 3840 * 1920, and the resolution of "video_2" is 2160 * 1080.

When I use ffmpeg to change the all resolutions to 2160 * 1080, it's worked.

**Origin**

I want to play several videos in sequence and meet a very strange behavior.

```
AVPlayerItem *item = ...;
if (!self.player) {
    self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
} else {
    [self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
}
[self.player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[self.player play];
```

For examples, I have three video files, such  as video_1, video_2 and video_3.

First, I set the playerItem with "video_1", then I replace with "video_2". That's ok.

But I replace with "video_3", the App has crashed. I can't find any device log on my iphone. Even more, when I was debugging and replacing with "video_3", it would disconnect the debug and no exception!

More information:

```
"video_2" can replace "video_1"
"video_1" can replace "video_2"
"video_3" can replace "video_2"
"video_3" can't replace "video_1"
"video_1" can't replace "video_3"
```

all videos can be played normal in alone.

Comment: I think I'm having the same problem as you. How did you eventually solve it? How did you remove the the strong reference?

Comment: Sovled by chance?

Answer (score 0):

> Try below code

```
if ([playerItemVideoOutput hasNewPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime]) {
    __unsafe_unretained ViewController *weakSelf = self; //create weak reference of your viewcontroller
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = [playerItemVideoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
    if(pixelBuffer) { //check if buffer exist
            [weakSelf.metalView.realTimeRender setPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer]; //use weakSelf here
            CFRelease(pixelBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand the answer? I'm having a similar issue but memory goes back to normal as soon as I stop the playback. Wondering what can be done about it…